# xcode version visible from the ipa

Tags: xcode, ipa

I have few versions of Xcode installed in my mac.
Lately I noticed that some of my code compiles and does what it should when built using xcode 4.6.3. But it does not behave as expected when built using xcode 4.4.1.

Question: Is it possible to know about the xcode version from the ipa (iOS application) itself?

Thanks and I shall really appreciate sharing your knowledge and thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can browse down to your Info.plist, there is a field called DTXcodeBuild and it will have a string value, like 4H1503. You can actually go to your xcode archive or .app and Open Package Contents, and then go to Products/Applications/YourApp.app and Open That package contents. The Info.plist should be in the root. That is where you'll find your DTXCodeBuild.

That is for an .app file. .IPA is a different though. It should be a binary. You could rename it to a .zip and look around, but chances are you won't find too much in there. Look at this thread discussing, ipa, renaming it, and the binary aspect of it:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4258197?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks Amit. I actually browsed the content of IPA after unzipping it using 7zip. I could find no information regarding the XCODE version in any of the files.